# When to use implicit and explicit operators in C#

Tags: c#, operator-keyword

Writing implicit and explicit type conversion operators is trivial.

I can find lots of documentation about ***how*** to write them, but very little about ***when***, or ***why*** to write them.

I've done some investigations into existing implementations; for example, [BigInteger](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Numerics/System/Numerics/BigInteger.cs,1131) from .NET's reference source:

```cs
public struct BigInteger : IFormattable, IComparable, IComparable<BigInteger>, IEquatable<BigInteger>
{
    public static implicit operator BigInteger(Byte value)
    {
        return new BigInteger(value);
    }

    public static explicit operator Byte(BigInteger value)
    {
        return checked((byte)((int)value));
    }
}
```

Given the excerpt above, what is the rational for using an `implicit` operator when converting from `Byte` to `BigInteger`, but using an `explicit` operator when converting from `BigInteger` to `Byte`?

Comment: I assume part of it is the fact that the operation is checked in the explicit operator. I would say implicit is preferable whenever the conversion is completely safe, and explicit is preferred if the operation is _NOT_ completely safe.

Comment: `but very little about when, or why to write them.` IMHO when you need/want them.

Comment: @DavidL That makes a lot of sense! Do you know if there's any documentation to back that up?

Comment: @MatthewLayton I was able to hunt some down and add an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, my assumption was that implicit operators should always be considered safe, whereas explicit operators *may* be safe but in some cases may need to be handled.

I found the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#102-implicit-conversions) on pre-defined implicit operators:

> The pre-defined implicit conversions always succeed and never cause
> exceptions to be thrown.
>
> Note: Properly designed user-defined implicit conversions should
> exhibit these characteristics as well. end note

In addition, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#1031-general) for explicit conversions does not give the same guarantees:

> The explicit conversions that are not implicit conversions are
> conversions that cannot be proven always to succeed, conversions that
> are known possibly to lose information, and conversions across domains
> of types sufficiently different to merit explicit notation.

This clearly backs up my assumption that implicit operators must ALWAYS be safe and never require exception handling, whereas explicit operators can and do throw exceptions, as in your example of the explicit operator that is `checked`.

Comment: Generally "safe" includes "does not lose precision" (which is why Byte -> int is implicit, but not other way around).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov absolutely true, although in this particular case the overflow is checked so rather than have a loss of precision, an exception is thrown. But in either case, an explicit conversion operator would be appropriate for BigInteger -> Byte and as you mentioned, implicit is appropriate for Byte -> int.

Comment: Just chiming in that this is a nice answer to an interesting question that I hadn't considered. Thanks